# How could I redirect an url with routes.php or htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

How could I redirect an url with routes.php or htaccess?

My homepage:

```
teszt.hu/onecontroller/oneaction/
teszt.hu/categories/index/
```

And the redirect:

```
teszt.hu/specword/categories/index/ => teszt.hu/categories/index/?s=specword
teszt.hu/specword/onecontroller/oneaction/ => teszt.hu/onecontroller/oneaction/?s=specword
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$accWebpages = '(webpage1|webpage2|specword)';

//Router::connect('/:accwebpage/:controller/:action', array(), array('pass' => array('accwebpage'), 'accwebpage' => $accWebpages));

Router::connect('/:accwebpage/', array('controller' => 'homes', 'action' => 'index'), array('pass' => array('accwebpage'), 'accwebpage' => $accWebpages));

Router::connect('/kategoria/:page/:category-:slug', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'index'), array('pass'=>array('page', 'category', 'slug'), 'page' => '[0-9]+', 'category' => '[0-9]+'));
Router::connect('/:accwebpage/kategoria/:page/:category-:slug', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'index'), array('pass'=>array('page', 'category', 'slug', 'accwebpage'), 'page' => '[0-9]+', 'category' => '[0-9]+', 'accwebpage' => $accWebpages));
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [CakePHP's Routes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) for this.

Read more about routes here:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Off the top of my head, I think it would be something like this:

```
Router::connect(
    '/specword/:controller/:action',
    array('?' => array('s'=>'specword')),
);
```